# Vue b-button doesn't take

Tags: vue.js

I am loading vue with  `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.7.14/vue.min.js"></script>`

Then I am trying to do

```
          <li v-for="(item, index) in searchResult.data.items">
            <b-button v-b-toggle.collapse-{{index}} variant="primary">{{ item.name }}</b-button>
            <b-collapse id=collapse-{{index}} class=mt-2>
              <b-card>
                <p class="card-text">{{ item.machine_code }}</p>
              </b-card>
            </b-collapse>
          </li>
```

It generates all items correctly so vue is running but each item looks like this

```
<li>
<b-button variant="primary">foo (correct item name)</b-button> 
<b-collapse id="collapse-{{index}}" class="mt-2">
<b-card>
<p class="card-text">bar (correct item machine code)</p>
</b-card>
</b-collapse>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try with:

```
<li v-for="(item, index) in searchResult.data.items">
    <b-button :v-b-toggle="'collapse-' + index" variant="primary">{{ item.name }}</b-button>
    <b-collapse :id="'collapse-' + index" class="mt-2">
        <b-card>
            <p class="card-text">{{ item.machine_code }}</p>
        </b-card>
    </b-collapse>
</li>
```

And **update**:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.7.14/vue.min.js"></script>
```

**to:**

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.7.14/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, that puts the numbers in place but there's no collapse in sight. The generated HTML is like `<b-button v-b-toggle="collapse-3" `. I took `b-button` from https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/collapse here, is there something I need to load besides vue.min.js perhap?

Comment: @chx Try with updated example :)

Comment: Almost there! The buttons now generate the correct HTML but clicking them doesn't do anything.

Comment: Wel .. debug it, also add `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.9.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
` popper.js

Comment: I added popper but not sure what to debug here. There are no errors in the console. Searching for v-b-toggle didn't result in much https://i.imgur.com/4gPhXsE.png (same for b-toggle)

Comment: I even [searched vuejs for toggle](https://github.com/search?q=org%3Avuejs+toggle+repo%3Avuejs%2Fvue&type=code&p=1) but I don't see where this is defined.